# Using powershell to add a network printer to a remote computer

Tags: powershell, network-printers

Let me preface by saying, I'm using Powershell version 5.1.19041.1320 opened as administrator using the Domain Administrator account that has proper rights.

I'm trying to add a network printer to other computers in the domain using Powershell and it's giving me a major fight. I can't figure out how I'm getting my syntax wrong.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-Printer -ComputerName [computer-name] -ConnectionName \\[printserver]\[printer-name]
Add-Printer : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Printer -ComputerName [computername] -ConnectionName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Printer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Add-Printer
```

(no brackets in the actual command, just showing placeholders here)

to be clear, the normal `Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\[printserver]\[printer-name]` *does* work on these machines from the machine itself, even on non-elevated PS.

Please help. Google has been failing me for the past hour or so, no solutions seem to work.
Also, remote CIM-sessions are not an option as the credentials on my domain are all smart cards so I can't just enter the username/password

Comment: It seems you cannot use parameter `-ComputerName` together with `-ConnectionName`.. You **can** use `-ComputerName` together with `-Location` and `-ShareName` though

Answer (score 0):

The issue that your probably running into here is that, printers are installed per user profile, especially if they are network printers. Running Add-Printer remotely probably wouldn't add the printer to the user logged in (assuming that there is a logged in user).

In the past when I had to add printers to users computers I would either use a logon script or group policy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding all printers from a server

```
$servername = Read-Host "Print Server Name"

$computerName= Read-Host "Computer Name"

$printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $servername -Full

 

 

    foreach ($printer in $printers){

    $portName = $printer.PortName

    $printerName = $printer.Name

    $connectionName =\\$serverName\$printerName

           
     
    if(($printer.Shared)){

      Write-Host "Adding $connectionName."

   

   Add-PrinterPort -Name $printer.Name -PrinterHostAddress $printer.PortName -ComputerName $computerName

   Add-PrinterDriver $printer.DriverName -ComputerName $computerName

   Add-Printer -Name $printer.Name -DriverName $printer.DriverName -PortName $printer.Name -ComputerName $computerName

    }

      }
```